# Do unique ring abilities stack?

Tags: dust-an-elysian-tail

I have always wondered if equipping rings with special abilities, like the ring of light's extra illumination, or any other rings with properties other than just stat multipliers stack. Do you know if they do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I have seen, yes they do.

Regen is a good marker of this. Find two rings with Regen on them and the amount of health Dust recovers per second should increase (indicated by green numbers popping out of your character).